# Is there a way to tell the character set available on command line interface?

Tags: php, command-line

I just made a [PHP script to display data as a table in command line interface](https://github.com/MarcBrillault/helpers#clitable), but when I try it on another environment than mine, the display is broken.

I'm awaiting something like this :

```
╔════╤══════════╤══════════════╗
║ id │ name     │ email        ║
╟────┼──────────┼──────────────╢
║  1 │ John Doe │ john@doe.com ║
║  2 │ Jane Doe │ jane@doe.com ║
╚════╧══════════╧══════════════╝
```

And I've got something like this :

```
ââââââ¤âââââââââââ¤âââââââââââââââ
â id â name     â email        â
ââââââ¼âââââââââââ¼âââââââââââââââ¢
â  1 â John Doe â john@doe.com â
â  2 â Jane Doe â jane@doe.com â
ââââââ§âââââââââââ§âââââââââââââââ
```

I guess the terminal isn't able to display multibyte characters, but is there a way to guess it *via* PHP? That way I would be able to switch between different assets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, that may be my putty configuration that was a mess. When forcing it to use UTF-8, all goes well.

But I don't think I can have the putty configuration, so I will consider it closed.